# OSError: [WinError 10022] An invalid argument was supplied

Tags: python, sockets

Im making a port scanner it through's this message here is my code but it checks one port 21 i have pasted output below

```
import socket
import os
host = input("Enter the host name or ip : ")
s = socket.socket()
s.settimeout(5)
p = 0;
s.close
port = [21,22,23,25,53,80,110,115,135,139,143,194,443,445,1433,3306,3389,5632,5900,6112]
while(p<=19):
    try:
        s.connect(('host', port[p]))
    except ConnectionRefusedError:
        print("Port %d is close" %(port[p]))
    except socket.timeout:
        print("Port %d is close" %(port[p]))
    else:
        print("Port %d is open" %(port[p]))
    p=p+1;
    s.close
```

---

On command line :

```
PS E:\Codes by me\Selenium py> python .\practice.py
Enter the host name or ip : 89.86.98.76
Port 21 is close # it checks one port
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\practice.py", line 11, in <module>
    s.connect((host, port[p]))
OSError: [WinError 10022] An invalid argument was supplied
```

Answer (score 3):

You are passing the literal string `'host'` as the host.  You should be passing the variable `host`:

```
s.connect((host, port[p]))
```

You are also not actually closing the socket each time, since you left off the parentheses in `s.close()`.  But if you did close the socket each time, you would have to create a new socket each time, instead of trying to reuse the same socket.  You can't reuse a closed socket.