# How to fix OSError when running Flask scripts

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, oserror

When running Flask scripts in localhost, I tried to access the webpages from another device in the same local network.
Although I'm able to view the webpages, I frequently noticed this error popping all of a sudden with random numbers near my IP in my console causing OSError and denying access for my later requests to the Flask server.

```
Exception happened during processing of request from ('192.168.0.4', 41252)
Exception happened during processing of request from ('192.168.0.4', 41250)
Traceback (most recent call last):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\socketserver.py", line 650, in process_request_thread
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\socketserver.py", line 650, in process_request_thread
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\socketserver.py", line 360, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\socketserver.py", line 720, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\socketserver.py", line 360, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\werkzeug\serving.py", line 329, in handle
    rv = BaseHTTPRequestHandler.handle(self)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\socketserver.py", line 720, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\http\server.py", line 426, in handle
    self.handle_one_request()
  File "C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\werkzeug\serving.py", line 329, in handle
    rv = BaseHTTPRequestHandler.handle(self)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\http\server.py", line 426, in handle
    self.handle_one_request()
  File "C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\werkzeug\serving.py", line 360, in handle_one_request
    self.raw_requestline = self.rfile.readline()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\socket.py", line 669, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
  File "C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\werkzeug\serving.py", line 360, in handle_one_request
    self.raw_requestline = self.rfile.readline()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\socket.py", line 669, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
OSError: [WinError 10022] An invalid argument was supplied
OSError: [WinError 10022] An invalid argument was supplied
----------------------------------------
----------------------------------------
Exception happened during processing of request from ('192.168.0.4', 41378)
Exception happened during processing of request from ('192.168.0.4', 41380)
Traceback (most recent call last):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\socketserver.py", line 650, in process_request_thread
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\socketserver.py", line 650, in process_request_thread
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\socketserver.py", line 360, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\socketserver.py", line 360, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\socketserver.py", line 720, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\socketserver.py", line 720, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\werkzeug\serving.py", line 329, in handle
    rv = BaseHTTPRequestHandler.handle(self)
  File "C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\werkzeug\serving.py", line 329, in handle
    rv = BaseHTTPRequestHandler.handle(self)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\http\server.py", line 426, in handle
    self.handle_one_request()
  File "C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\werkzeug\serving.py", line 360, in handle_one_request
    self.raw_requestline = self.rfile.readline()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\http\server.py", line 426, in handle
    self.handle_one_request()
  File "C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\werkzeug\serving.py", line 360, in handle_one_request
    self.raw_requestline = self.rfile.readline()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\socket.py", line 669, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\socket.py", line 669, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
OSError: [WinError 10022] An invalid argument was supplied
OSError: [WinError 10022] An invalid argument was supplied
----------------------------------------
----------------------------------------
```

For all I know, I know nothing about sockets or other things thats in my error.
How do i stop such errors from happenning after all I'm just rendering a HTML template as a response?

**Edit :**

I'm adding a part of my Flask script here from which I still get the error. And again the error is something that occurs when I try to access my webpages from other devices connected in the network

```
from flask import *

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template("home.html")


@app.route('/download')
def downloads():
    return render_template("downloads.html")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=5000 , debug = True)
```

This time also I got similar error as follows

```
----------------------------------------
Exception happened during processing of request from ('192.168.0.5', 42834)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\socketserver.py", line 650, in process_request_thread
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\socketserver.py", line 360, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\socketserver.py", line 720, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\werkzeug\serving.py", line 329, in handle
    rv = BaseHTTPRequestHandler.handle(self)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\http\server.py", line 426, in handle
    self.handle_one_request()
  File "C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\werkzeug\serving.py", line 360, in handle_one_request
    self.raw_requestline = self.rfile.readline()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\socket.py", line 669, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
OSError: [WinError 10022] An invalid argument was supplied
----------------------------------------
```

Comment: Hi there. You're going to need to post some offending code for us to help. A full example would be helpful.

Comment: I hope this code is sufficient enough to replicate the error I'm getting.

Comment: Hmmm, I don't see any problem with your code. I do see [some similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43330897/oserror-winerror-10022-an-invalid-argument-was-supplied-windows-10-python) (and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31765310/oserror-winerror-10022-an-invalid-argument-was-supplied)), but they seem to relate to directly using the network stack. I wonder if Flask has Windows-specific bug?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what happens if you run this using Windows Subsystem For Linux's Python interpreter instead of a Windows Python interpreter?

Comment: Both the questions from the links you had shared has imported socket module and used it in some way so that they got an error like me. But I'm not using it at least I didn't import it (maybe Flask did?). It might be a bug but if it was everyone should face the same right? So that it should have got fixed by now. As for " what happens if you run this using Windows Subsystem For Linux's Python interpreter instead of a Windows Python interpreter?" this, I'm sorry I don't understand this.

Comment: I'm thinking since it's a Windows-specific error, perhaps there's a bug in Flask itself on Windows. But you could remove Windows from the equation by using WSL.

Comment: Well, the actual error itself is caused by android mobile. And weirdly enough I found the same error with Django today.